# Entropy of edit distance

Tags: pr.probability, entropy, co.combinatorics

The edit or [Levenshtein](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levenshtein_distance) distance between two strings is the minimum number of single character insertions, deletions and substitutions to transform one string into another.   If we take random binary strings $A$ and $B$ of the same length $n$, is it known what the entropy of the edit distance between $A$ and $B$ is?

**Update.**  I would be happy with a proof that the entropy is asymptotically  $c \log n$ for some (unknown) $c>0$ as suggested by Anthony Quas (or even $(\Theta(\log{n})$ which potentially saves having to prove convergence).

Comment: Can you clarify exactly what you mean by "entropy of the edit distance"?

Comment: @VaughnClimenhaga  If $A$ and $B$ are random variables (in this case over random binary strings) then the edit distance between $A$ and $B$ will also be a random variable with some distribution. As another example, if we are interested in the Hamming distance rather than the edit distance then the entropy of the Hamming distance is $H(B(n,1/2))$ which is known.

Comment: This is also known in ergodic theory as the $\bar f$-distance. There are known linear lower bounds on the expected $\bar f$-distance between random strings of length $n$, so treating the $\bar f$ distance as a random variable, it will presumably be a unimodal distribution whose standard deviation is a power of $n$. Hence the entropy of this random variable will be approximately of the form $c\log n$.

Comment: @AnthonyQuas. Thank you. Do you know a reference for the lower bounds on expected f-distance? 

Comment: @AnthonyQuas I found a definition of $\bar{f}$-distance on page 3 of http://www.univ-rouen.fr/LMRS/Persopage/Janvresse/Publi/pascal_adic_is_LB.pdf . However this is the length of the longest common subsequence (essentially) not $n$  minus the edit distance I think. Those values can be arbitrarily far apart. Take for example two strings $00001111$ and $11110000$. The LCS length is $n/2$ and $n$ minus the edit distance is $0$. 

Comment: I'd still would like to know the definition or a link to a definition of "entropy of the edit distance".

Comment: @WłodzimierzHolsztyński If the inputs are uniformly random than the edit distance between them is also a discrete random variable and I believe the OP is referring to the Shannon entropy of this random variable.

Answer (score 3):

This is not a complete answer and may not tell you anything you don't already know, but it's too long for a comment.

You can get an estimate on the number of words at an edit distance of $k$ from a given word of length $n$ by using the arguments in the proof of Lemma 2.6 in [this paper](http://arxiv.org/abs/1304.5497).  (The lemma is on page 10 and its proof is on page 28.)

The idea is that if a word $w$ is at an edit distance of $k$ from a word $v$, then one can get from $v$ to $w$ via the following steps:

1. insert $k$ copies of the symbol 'e' (for 'edit') into the word $v$;
2. one by one, go through the symbols 'e' and either change the symbol immediately before it, delete the symbol immediately before it, or insert a symbol immediately before it, and then delete the 'e'.

Step 1 gives a word of length $n+k$ with $k$ occurrences of the symbol 'e', so there are ${n+k\choose k}$ possibilities after this step.  Then step 2 gives at most $3^k$ possible words for each of those possibilities, so for a fixed word $v$ of length $n$ one obtains the bound
$$
\#\{w \mid \text{edit distance from $v$ to $w$ is $k$}\} \leq 3^k {n+k \choose k}.
$$
For small $k$ this is a reasonable bound; in particular when $k\ll n$ this is not much larger than ${n\choose k}$, the number of words a Hamming distance of $k$ away.  The problem is that for larger values of $k$ the procedure described above succumbs to a lot of overcounting, so it's not clear what the actual bound should be.

Comment: Thank you. Maybe this questions turns out to be surprisingly hard.